# How to get back test results in MTM after new build is assigned

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, lab-management

we use microsoft test lab managment for testing, lately admins chnged build from 32 to 64 bit, so build in use for test plan was changed also, what we get is all tests, that were run become active and all test results were lost. can we get those statuses back.
Thanks.